# mysql: is there a way to catch each sql error that occurs and to insert it into a table?

Tags: mysql

I'm building an application using Java and Mysql 5.1. i would like to know if it's possible using mysql alone to catch sql errors and to insert them into a database.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. What would happen to an error inserting into the error table?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html